# Converting SQL query to codeigniter active record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on a private message app using CodeIgniter.
I have 3 tables:

1. conversations
2. conversations_messages
3. conversations_members.

I am trying to join the tables by matching the conversations `ids` and fetch all the messages for the user who's logged in.

This is the standard sql query

```
    SELECT 
    'conversations','conversation_id',
    'conversations','conversation_subject',
    MAX('conversations_messages','message_date') AS 'conversation_last_reply'
FROM 'conversations'
LEFT JOIN 'conversations_messages' ON 'conversations'.'conversation_id' = 'conversations_messages'.'conversation_id'
INNER JOIN 'conversations_members' ON 'conversations'.'conversation_id' = 'conversations_members'.'conversation_id'
WHERE 'conversations_members', 'user_id' = $sender_id
AND 'conversations_members','conversation_deleted' = 0
GROUP BY 'conversations'.'conversation_id'
ORDER BY 'conversation_last_reply'  DESC";
```

Its a big query, hence; I'm not sure how to convert it to CodeIgniter active records or simply make it run with the framework.

Any corrections would be appreciated too.

Comment: Try your query in phpmyadmin and see what error occured. one thing i noticed.. you used " 'conversations_members', 'user_id' = $sender_id " instead of 'conversations_members.user_id' = $sender_id in where condition.

Comment: thank you .... i used it and it worked like a charm

Comment: if you find it useful then please give upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code with **CodeIgniter** active record.

```
 $this->db->select('conversations, conversation_id, conversation_subject');
 $this->db->select_max('conversations_messages.message_date', 'conversation_last_reply');
 $this->db->from('conversations');
 // Joining with conversations_messages table 
 $this->db->join('conversations_messages','conversations.id=conversations_messages.conversation_id','left');
 $this->db->join('conversations_members','conversations.id= conversations_members.conversation_id','inner');
 $this->db->where('conversations_members.user_id',$sender_id);
 $this->db->where('conversations_members.conversation_deleted','0');
 $this->db->group_by('conversations.conversation_id');
 $this->db->order_by('conversation_last_reply');
 // Get the results from db
 $query = $this->db->get();
 // Result array contains the records selected
 $result_array = $query->result_array();
```

Happy coding

Naseem

Comment: seems like this will work , but there's one more error.  "Field conversations unknown field in list" . i am sure i have conversations as a table in my database. BY THE WAY , conversations, conversations_members and conversations_messages are tables in my database . thanks for your help naseem!

Comment: Could you please check whether conversions table have field ''conversations' ..? If everything is ok now ,dont forget to mark my answers as right answer and vote for my answers.

Comment: Rich, I have updated the code. There was two conversations in the select query. I just removed it .

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->db->select('conversations, conversation_id, conversation_subject');
 $this->db->select_max('conversations_messages.message_date', 'conversation_last_reply');
 $this->db->from('conversations');
 // Joining with conversations_messages table 
 $this->db->join('conversations_messages','conversations.id=conversations_messages.conversation_id','left');
 $this->db->join('conversations_members','conversations.id= conversations_members.conversation_id','inner');
 $this->db->where('conversations_members.user_id',$sender_id);
 $this->db->where('conversations_members.conversation_deleted','0');
 $this->db->group_by('conversations.conversation_id');
 $this->db->order_by('conversation_last_reply');
 // Get the results from db
 $query = $this->db->get();
 // Result array contains the records selected
 $result_array = $query->result_array();
```